# Ruby - Writing filenames from subfolders to a txt file

Tags: ruby

I have 385 subfolders in a directory, each containing a CSV file along with several pdfs. I'm trying to find a way to go through each subfolder and write a list of the pdfs to a txt file. (I realize there are better languages out there to do this than Ruby, but I'm new to programming and it's the only language I know.)

I have code that gets the job done, but the problem I'm running into is it's listing the subfolder directory as well. Example: Instead of writing "document.pdf" to a text file, it's writing "subfolder/document.pdf."

Can someone please show me how to write just the pdf filename?

Thanks in advance! Here's my code:

```
class Account
  attr_reader :account_name, :account_acronym, :account_series
  attr_accessor :account_directory

  def initialize
    @account_name = account_name
    @account_series = account_series
    @account_directory = account_directory
  end

  #prompts user for account name and record series so it can create the directory
  def validation_account
    print "What account?"
    account_name = gets.chomp
    print "What Record Series? "
    account_series = gets.chomp
    account_directory = "c:/Processed Batches Clone/" + account_name +  "/" + account_series + "/Data"
    puts account_directory
    return account_directory
  end
end

processed_batches_dir = Account.new

#changes pwd to account directory
Dir.chdir "#{processed_batches_dir.validation_account}"

# pdf list
processed_docs = []

# iterates through subfolders and creates list
Dir.glob("**/*.pdf") { |file|
  processed_docs.push(file)
  }

# writes list to .txt file
File.open("processed_batches.txt","w") { |file|
  file.puts(processed_docs)
  }
```

Comment: That's funny, your comment on Ruby. I've been programming for decades and have used at least a dozen languages, and I would recommend any new programmer to start with Ruby! It's my favorite.

Answer (score 0):

There may be a better way, but you could always `split` on the last slash in the path:

```
Dir.glob('**/*.pdf').each do |file_with_path|
  processed_docs.push(file_with_path.split('/').last)
end
```